# How to access a vector securely on C++?

Tags: c++

I have the followin vector:

```
std::vector<std::pair<std::function<void(iter_type, iter_type)>, bool>> functionList;
```

and at some point, a code is doing:

```
functionList[index].second = enable;
```

which is causing a crash

How can I safely verify if there's an object in this `index` so I can modify?

https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/container/vector/operator_at says that `operator[]` returns a reference, but I tried to check it for null and couldn't.

Also, what does `reference` means in `reference operator[]( size_type pos );`? Certainly not the same as `&`

Comment: How are you obtaining the value `index`? Are you checking it lies between `0` and `functionList.size()`?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Use `.at(index)` and catch the exception, or check `index < vec.size()` before calling `[]`.

References in C++ are not null, they are aliases.  Pointers can be null in C++.

Comment: also: if (functionList[index] != null)

Comment: what's the difference between `reference` in the return type versus `&`?

Comment: `std::vector<T>::reference` is just a `typedef` for `T&`.

Comment: @AntoninGAVREL Ahem, no.

Comment: so a reference cannot be null, but when I access some item that does not exist, does it mean that I'm acessing random data that causes undefined behaviour?

Comment: @GuerlandoOCs With `.operator[]()`? Yes. That's why you have to check that the accessed index is smaller than the container's `size()`. `.at()` throws an exception when you try to access a non existing object.

Answer (score 0):

There are three ways to use a vector without risking undefined behavior from an out-of-bounds access. In order of preference, they are:

- calculate the index correctly
- check that the index is in bounds before using it
- instead of `functionlist[index]` use `functionList.at(index)`, which will throw an exception for a bad index